# TensorFlow restoring from NN does not work

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I am struggling with restoring values from NN in tensorflow. I tried to follow the examples on net, and here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


np.random.seed(1000) # for repro
function_to_learn = lambda x: np.sin(x) + 0.1*np.random.randn(*x.shape)

NUM_HIDDEN_NODES = 2 
NUM_EXAMPLES = 1000 
TRAIN_SPLIT = .8
MINI_BATCH_SIZE = 100 
NUM_EPOCHS = 500  


all_x = np.float32(np.random.uniform(-2*math.pi, 2*math.pi, (1, NUM_EXAMPLES))).T
np.random.shuffle(all_x)
train_size = int(NUM_EXAMPLES*TRAIN_SPLIT)
trainx = all_x[:train_size]
validx = all_x[train_size:]
trainy = function_to_learn(trainx)
validy = function_to_learn(validx)



plt.figure()
plt.scatter(trainx, trainy, c='green', label='train')
plt.scatter(validx, validy, c='red', label='validation')
plt.legend()


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="Y")


w_h = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, NUM_HIDDEN_NODES],name="w_h"))
b_h = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, NUM_HIDDEN_NODES],name="b_h"))
w_o = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_HIDDEN_NODES,1],name="w_o"))
b_o = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1],name="b_o"))



def init_weights(shape, init_method='xavier', xavier_params = (None, None)):
    if init_method == 'zeros':
        return tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape, dtype=tf.float32))
    elif init_method == 'uniform':
        return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01, dtype=tf.float32))



def model(X, num_hidden = NUM_HIDDEN_NODES):
    w_h = init_weights([1, num_hidden], 'uniform' )
    b_h = init_weights([1, num_hidden], 'zeros')
    h = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_h) + b_h)

    w_o = init_weights([num_hidden, 1], 'xavier', xavier_params=(num_hidden, 1))
    b_o = init_weights([1, 1], 'zeros')
    return tf.matmul(h, w_o) + b_o



yhat = model(X, NUM_HIDDEN_NODES)

train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(tf.nn.l2_loss(yhat - Y))


plt.figure()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for v in tf.all_variables():
        print v.name



saver = tf.train.Saver()

errors = []

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for i in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
        for start, end in zip(range(0, len(trainx), MINI_BATCH_SIZE), range(MINI_BATCH_SIZE, len(trainx), MINI_BATCH_SIZE)):
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trainx[start:end], Y: trainy[start:end]})

        mse = sess.run(tf.nn.l2_loss(yhat - validy),  feed_dict={X:validx})
        errors.append(mse)
        if i%100 == 0:
            print "epoch %d, validation MSE %g" % (i, mse)
            print sess.run(w_h)
            saver.save(sess,"/Python/tensorflow/res/save_net.ckpt", global_step = i)



    print " ******* AFTR *******"
    for v in tf.all_variables():
        print v.name
    plt.plot(errors)
    plt.xlabel('#epochs')
    plt.ylabel('MSE')
```

******* to get the restore values, I tried:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


NUM_HIDDEN_NODES = 2 



#SECOND PART TO GET THE STORED VALUES

w_h = tf.Variable(np.arange(NUM_HIDDEN_NODES).reshape(1, NUM_HIDDEN_NODES), dtype=tf.float32, name='w_h')
b_h = tf.Variable(np.arange(NUM_HIDDEN_NODES).reshape(1, NUM_HIDDEN_NODES), dtype=tf.float32, name='b_h')

w_o = tf.Variable(np.arange(NUM_HIDDEN_NODES).reshape(NUM_HIDDEN_NODES, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='w_o')
b_o = tf.Variable(np.arange(1).reshape(1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='b_o')



saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state("/Python/tensorflow/res/")
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        # Restores from checkpoint
        saver.restore(sess, "/Python/tensorflow/res/save_net.ckpt-400")
        print "Model loaded"
    else:
        print "No checkpoint file found"

    print("weights:", sess.run(w_h))
    print("biases:", sess.run(b_h))
```

Your help is greatly appreciated and I am almost giving up on this.

Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 2):

It seems the checkpoint file you want to restore your variables from is different from the current variable/shape of existing code.

Save: (if substitute it with constants from definitions above)

```
w_h = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 5],name="w_h"))
b_h = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 5],name="b_h"))
w_o = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5,1],name="w_o"))
b_o = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1],name="b_o"))
```

Restore:

```
w_h = tf.Variable(np.arange(10).reshape(1, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name='w_h')
b_h = tf.Variable(np.arange(10).reshape(1, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name='b_h')

w_o = tf.Variable(np.arange(10).reshape(10, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='w_o')
b_o = tf.Variable(np.arange(1).reshape(1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='b_o')
```

To prevent these types of problems, try to use functions for training and inference so all your code will same variables and constants.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two sets of weights, once globally and second time when you call `init_weights`. The second set of variables is the one that's getting optimized, but both sets are saved.

In your eval code, you are creating this set of variables once, so your restore only restores the first set, which has not been modified after initialization.

The solution is to either factor out model creation code so that exactly same graph is created during training and during eval, or to use [meta_graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/meta_graph/index.html) which will recreate graph structure during restore.